# extending href programmatically in typo3

Tags: html, typo3, usability

What's the best way to extend the attribute href programmatically in Typo3?

The links were setted by RTE like

```
<a class="download" target="_blank" href="fileadmin/ablage/test_material/pdf_1.pdf">
```

and shall be changed to

```
<a class="download" target="_blank" href="fileadmin/ablage/test_material/pdf_1.pdf#zoom=100">
```

Comment: You should first write out your entire question, and then press submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested code:

you could try to add the section to the parameter

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link.typolink.parameter.append = TEXT
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link.typolink.parameter.append {
  value = #zoom=100
  if.equals.data = parameters:0
  if.equals.substring = -3,3
  if.value = pdf
}
```

or you can try to use "section"

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link.typolink.section.cObject = TEXT
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link.typolink.section.cObject {
  value = zoom=100
  if.equals.data = parameters:0
  if.equals.substring = -3,3
  if.value = pdf
}
```

BUT the most important issue is the "if" statement.  I assume that the first parameter is the name of the file (i do not remember). The last 3 charachters should be "pdf". If you use DAM you need to retrieve the UID and get the filetype from there.

Just a rought guess, this could give you a hint, which params do you have:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link.typolink.parameter.append = TEXT
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link.typolink.parameter.append {
  data = parameters : allParams
  htmlSpecialChars = 1
  wrap = ?debug=|
}
```

Just a side note: this would be affect all RTE fields!

Comment: Thanks, for the solution. It worked after I had changed "parameters:0" to "parameters : allParams".

Comment: perhaps the parameters has to be named? do not remember. But parameters:allParams will not work, if you set an class or an target

Answer (score 0):

If there is a fixed class for that link, you could use jQuery...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.download').each(function(){
    var linkhref = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', linkhref + '#zoom=100');
  });
});
```

Comment: A fixed Id is given but for all possible file downloads. I could extend your code with a filter for filetype pdf. Rather I would prefer a typoscript solution because that would be rendered and cached on server instead of client. Thanks for inspiration anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This code do it.

```
parseFunc_RTE.tags.link.typolink.parameter.append = TEXT
parseFunc_RTE.tags.link.typolink.parameter.append {
    value = #zoom=100
    if.equals.data = parameters : allParams
    if.equals.substring = -3,3
    if.value = pdf
}
```